# Series of modified Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, mathematical-physics

There is a known identity to evaluate a sum of the form

$$\sum_{n\geq1} \rho^n I_n(\omega) $$

Where $\rho>0$, $\omega >0$ and $I_n$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

???

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure there exists a nice closed form expression, but using integral representation of modified Bessel function, your sum can be written as the following integral: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\rho^n I_n(\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}
\frac{\rho \left(\cos\theta-\rho\right)e^{\omega\cos\theta}d\theta}{1+\rho^2-2\rho\cos \theta}.$$
This should be rather efficient representation from the point of view of numerics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ S  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^nI_n(y)  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{y}{2} \right)^{2k + n}}{k!\Gamma(n+k+1)}$$

$$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{xy}{2} \right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{y^2}{4} \right)^k }{k!(n+k)!}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{xy}{2} \right)^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{xy}{2} \right)^n \left( \frac{y^2}{4} \right)^k}{k!(n+k)!} $$

we can interchange

$$ = e^{\frac{xy}{2}} - 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{y^2}{4} \right)^k}{k!} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{xy}{2} \right)^n}{(n+k)!} $$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{xy}{2} \right)^n}{(n+k)!}  = \frac{\gamma \left(k,\frac{xy}{2} \right)}{\left(\frac{xy}{2} \right)^k (k-1)!e^{-\frac{xy}{2}}} - \frac{1}{k!}$$

$$ \Rightarrow S = e^{\frac{xy}{2}} - 1   + e^{\frac{xy}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k\gamma \left(k,\frac{xy}{2} \right)\left(\frac{y}{2x} \right)^k}{k!^2} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{y^2}{4} \right)^k}{k!^2} $$

if this is right i think it became kinda easier

please edit if you saw anything wrong

Comment: What is $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$?

Comment: hi look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: I think that there is an error when you multiply at the end $y^2/4$ by $(xy/2)^{-1}$

Comment: i will edit :-)

Comment: @StreetDog do you know how to continue ???!!!!!

Comment: What i'm really instersted about is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(x^n - \frac{1}{x^n}\right)I_n(y)$$ On the particular case where $x=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}$ and $y = 2\sqrt{(a+b)(a-b)}$ \\ I'm trying to evaluate the whole expression now

Comment: please upvote me i'm tired from writing this .

Comment: @what'sup are you here?

Comment: @Chris'ssis hahahahaha , i'm here . :-)